# 80+ Mail console messages per seconds: "no entry for mailbox id <X> in the cache; this should never happen"

Tags: mail.app, catalina, console

Mail rarely below 30% cpu on a 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 …
-> could be 100% of one core …

- fan on (very loud), top of the notebook very hot,
- laptop very slow to react/respond to inputs
- making Mail unusable / stopping it makes the machine quieter/colder/reactive again
- Weird part is: trying to troubleshoot, when toggling off all mail accounts (and even tried notes), the Mail program is still sending the message:
  "no entry for mailbox id [variable ids] in the cache this should never happen" to the console - until some timeout seen once - making me think the issue was solved, but it came back.
- all the same Mail/Notes accounts seem to be ok on iOS though …
- no related topics found on google, except problem with accountsd maybe …
- seems to be a feature post install Catalina ...
- although similar messages appeared in this thread in 2009:
  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1891181
- suggestions/comments/same experience anyone :) ?

Comment: [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1891181) at Apple Communities might help. You will need an app capable of editing .plist files such as Property List Editor or BBEdit.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me and this have solved :

- Quit Apple Mail
- Go to folder : ~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData (you should use the Finder "Go" menu then "Go to folder" because this folder is normally hidden.
  ~ is your user home folder.
- Rename all "Envelope Index xxx" on "--Envelope Index xxx". You should normally have 3 (on the screenshot I have 5 files but it's because Apple Mail was launched when I take it).
- Launch Apple Mail

Normally, Apple Mail will re-create this files that are cached data and all could be solved.

Jérôme.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It just did the trick! Chapeau bas :)